# What's the value of "gasLimit = 21000" of Ethereum in Polygon?

Tags: gas, polygon, gas-limit

In Ethereum the gasLimit is 21000. **The constant.**

I haven't found anywhere the value of it for Polygon, though.  How much is it? For a token as well as for MATIC itself.

I've found the number 57000 on an explorer in a real TX. Yet I haven't been able to find a confirmation for it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **gas usage** for simple transactions like transferring of native tokens on Ethereum as well as Polygon remain `21000` gas units mostly, but it can increase during periods of high network congestion.

However, you can specify any `gasLimit` as long as it's within the constraints of the block gas limit, as transactions must fit within the block gas limit to be included in a block. You can read more about this from here:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/161698/91017

So, if you specify the `gasLimit` as `21000` (or don't specify at all, as it's the default) for transferring of ether (i.e., native token), then it'll utilise 100% of that as **gas usage**. Like this:

[image]

And, if you specify the higher `gasLimit` (say `50000`), then most of the times, it'll utilise only `21000` (unless there's some network congestion, high usage or so), and the remaining gas will be refunded to you, like this:

[image]

Comment: you've mentioned Ether. Does that work in Polygon the same way, though? In Polygon it's a dynamic value, whereas in Ethereum a static one

Comment: Ether means native token, which means ETH in case of Ethereum and MATIC in case of Polygon. Please read the explanation carefully, it's **not static**, neither in Ethereum nor in Polygon. Also, the transaction screenshots attached are of Polygon only.

Comment: Is `21000` in Ethereum not static?

Comment: @kriss100, this might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/92433/91017.